# How can I run a local Django dev server with SSL using a .local domain?

Tags: django

I have a Django site that uses cross-site requests between subdomains. In order for this to work, I need FQDNs and SSL during local development.

I'm using `dnsmasq` to resolve .local domains, and `runserver_plus` to run on HTTPS:

```
./manage.py runserver_plus --cert=/tmp/mysite.cert
```

But when I go to https://mysite.local:8000, I get a certificate error in the browser:

```
ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID
```

Is there any way to develop locally with a valid certificate?

Comment: Is it a self-signed certificate? Did you configure your browser to allow it

Comment: Yes, `runserver_plus` auto-generates the self-signed `.crt` and `.key` files.  I'm not sure how to configure chrome to allow it

Comment: Actually, I just realized that `runserver_plus` is generating a cert for `localhost` and not `mysite.localdomain`, so I probably need to generate my own keypair? But then, how do I add that keypair to chrome? I tried adding the "Authority" tab in the certificate settings, but it says it's not a valid CA.

Comment: I found https://www.nullalo.com/en/chrome-how-to-install-self-signed-ssl-certificates/ tutorial about importing certifiates in chrome, not sure if it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much research, I ended up making a custom script to generate local SSL certs for a wildcard domain such as `*.mysite.local`. For wildcard to work, a [SAN](https://www.ssl.com/faqs/what-is-a-san-certificate/) certificate is required. For the cert to be imported into Chrome, I needed a valid CA certificate as well.

This script generates the necessary `.crt` and `.key` files, as well as the CA cert.

```py
import shutil
import sys
import re
import os
import subprocess
from io import StringIO
from configparser import ConfigParser
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.exceptions import ImproperlyConfigured


def generate_local_ssl_certs(domain, output_dir, stdout=None):
    if not stdout:
        stdout = sys.stdout

    cnf_filename = os.path.join(output_dir, f'{domain}.cnf')
    ca_key_filename = os.path.join(output_dir, f'{domain}.ca.key')
    ca_crt_filename = os.path.join(output_dir, f'{domain}.ca.crt')
    pem_filename = os.path.join(output_dir, f'{domain}.pem')
    csr_filename = os.path.join(output_dir, f'{domain}.csr')
    key_filename = os.path.join(output_dir, f'{domain}.key')
    crt_filename = os.path.join(output_dir, f'{domain}.crt')

    files = (
        cnf_filename, ca_key_filename, ca_crt_filename, csr_filename, key_filename,
        crt_filename, pem_filename
    )

    # clean up any existing files
    for file in files:
        try:
            os.remove(file)
        except Exception:
            pass

    config = ConfigParser()
    config.optionxform = lambda option: option

    # Determine location of openssl.conf
    openssl_bin = shutil.which('openssl')
    if not openssl_bin:
        raise ImproperlyConfigured(
            "The openssl binary could not be found on your system. Please make "
            "sure you have""OpenSSL installed.")

    OPENSSL_CONF = os.environ.get('OPENSSL_CONF')
    if OPENSSL_CONF is None:
        # find openssl installation
        out = subprocess.check_output([openssl_bin, 'version', '-d'])
        match = re.match(r'OPENSSLDIR: "(.+)"', out.decode())
        openssl_dir = match.group(1)
        OPENSSL_CONF = os.path.join(openssl_dir, 'openssl.cnf')

    with open(OPENSSL_CONF, 'r') as stream:
        config.read_string('[top]\n' + stream.read())

    config.set(' v3_ca ', 'subjectKeyIdentifier', 'hash')
    config.set(' v3_ca ', 'authorityKeyIdentifier', 'keyid:always,issuer')
    config.set(' v3_ca ', 'basicConstraints', 'critical, CA:TRUE, pathlen:3')
    config.set(' v3_ca ', 'keyUsage', 'critical, cRLSign, keyCertSign')
    config.set(' v3_ca ', 'nsCertType', 'sslCA, emailCA')

    config.set(' v3_req ', 'basicConstraints', 'CA:FALSE')
    config.set(' v3_req ', 'keyUsage', 'nonRepudiation, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment')
    config.set(' v3_req ', 'subjectAltName', '@alt_names')
    config.remove_option(' v3_req ', 'extendedKeyUsage')

    config.add_section(' alt_names ')
    config.set(' alt_names ', 'DNS.1', domain)
    config.set(' alt_names ', 'DNS.2', '*.{}'.format(domain))

    config.set(' req ', 'req_extensions', 'v3_req')

    # Write config to string
    temp = StringIO()
    config.write(temp)
    temp.seek(0)
    config_str = temp.read()

    # Remove first line from config
    config_str = '\n'.join(config_str.splitlines()[1:])

    with open(cnf_filename, 'w') as f:
        f.write(config_str)

    def openssl_run(*args):
        args = ('openssl',) + args
        stdout.write(subprocess.check_output(args).decode())

    openssl_run('genrsa', '-out', ca_key_filename, '2048')
    openssl_run(
        'req', '-new', '-x509', '-subj', f'/CN={domain}', '-extensions', 'v3_ca', '-days',
        '3650', '-key', ca_key_filename, '-sha256', '-out', ca_crt_filename, '-config',
        cnf_filename)
    openssl_run('genrsa', '-out', key_filename, '2048')
    openssl_run(
        'req', '-subj', f'/CN={domain}', '-extensions', 'v3_req', '-sha256', '-new', '-key',
        key_filename, '-out', csr_filename)
    openssl_run(
        'x509', '-req', '-extensions', 'v3_req', '-days', '3650', '-sha256', '-in',
        csr_filename, '-CA', ca_crt_filename, '-CAkey', ca_key_filename, '-CAcreateserial',
        '-out', crt_filename, '-extfile', cnf_filename)
    openssl_run('x509', '-in', crt_filename, '-text', '-noout')

    stdout.write(
        "\n------------\n"
        "Successfully created SSL certificates.\n\n"
        "You must now add the certificate CA to your browser's trusted certs.\n"
        "In Chrome, go to chrome://settings/certificates, click the 'Authorities' tab, click "
        f"'Import', then select the following file: \n{ca_crt_filename}.\n\n")
```